PowerBI Chart of monthly differences with specific month labels
I'm going to make in PowerBI chart with monthly differences in sales. I have data as below - sales and two types of date:



DATE_YYYYMM
DATE_MMMYY
SALES




202401
Jan'24
100


202401
Jan'24
110


202402
Feb'24
110


202402
Feb'24
120


202403
Mar'24
120


202403
Mar'24
130


202404
Apr'24
130


202404
Apr'24
140



I wrote measure to count sales differences between each month:
MONTHLY_SALES_VS_PREVIOUS_MONTH = 
VAR _SELECTEDVALUE = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[DATE_YYYYMM])
VAR _MAX_DATE = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[DATE_YYYYMM]), ALL('Table'[DATE_YYYYMM]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[DATE_YYYYMM] < _SELECTEDVALUE))
VAR PREVIOUS_PERFORMANCE = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[SALES]), 'Table'[DATE_YYYYMM] = _MAX_DATE)
VAR CURRENT_PERFORMANCE = SUM('Table'[SALES])
RETURN CURRENT_PERFORMANCE / PREVIOUS_PERFORMANCE - 1

When I use this measure to make a chart in PowerBI, I have something like this:

It is correct, but I want to have chart with other type of date on X-axis. Like this:

I tried to modify my measure, but it don't want to work with this second type of date. Is there any way to reach this result?

You need a proper date table and star schema but if you want a quick hack, try this.
MONTHLY_SALES_VS_PREVIOUS_MONTH = 
VAR _SELECTEDVALUE = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[DATE_YYYYMM])
VAR _MAX_DATE = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[DATE_YYYYMM]), ALL('Table'[DATE_YYYYMM]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[DATE_YYYYMM] < _SELECTEDVALUE))
VAR PREVIOUS_PERFORMANCE = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[SALES]), 'Table'[DATE_YYYYMM] = _MAX_DATE, REMOVEFILTERS())
VAR CURRENT_PERFORMANCE = SUM('Table'[SALES])
RETURN  IF(_SELECTEDVALUE <> 202401,    CURRENT_PERFORMANCE / PREVIOUS_PERFORMANCE -1)


